# Github organization for joined maintenance of JavaScript repositories / NPM packages?

Tags: javascript, github

Too many times I bumped into the state of JavaScript packages not being updated anymore. Most of the time, an update of the dependencies, followed by a new release on npmjs.com is all what's needed to keep such libraries going.

Does there exist a Github organization which offers joined maintenance of such libraries, also having the ownership of the corresponding package listing on npmjs.org?

If you look at configuration management tools like Chef or Puppet, the communities came up with the following Github organizations which are highly effective:

- Puppet: [Vox Pupuli](https://github.com/voxpupuli)
- Chef: [Chef Cookbooks](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks)

Ringo